# Cannot read property 'spreadsheets' of undefined - google spreadSheet

Tags: javascript, api, spreadsheet

I have problem  like as title. I  sign in oauth2 and google return error

"Cannot read property 'spreadsheets' of undefined". I tried copy sample from google page and same error;

```
   function makeApiCall() {
        var spreadsheetBody = {
            // TODO: Add desired properties to the request body.
        };

        var request = gapi.client.sheets.spreadsheets.create({}, spreadsheetBody);
        request.then(function(response) {
            // TODO: Change code below to process the `response` object:
            console.log(response.result);
        }, function(reason) {
            console.error('error: ' + reason.result.error.message);
        });
    }

    function initClient() {


        var SCOPE = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets';

        gapi.client.init({
            'apiKey': 'myke',
            'clientId': 'myclientID',
            'scope': SCOPE,
            // 'discoveryDocs': ['https://sheets.googleapis.com/$discovery/rest?version=v4'],
        }).then(function() {
            gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().signIn();
            gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().isSignedIn.listen(updateSignInStatus);
            updateSignInStatus(gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().isSignedIn.get());
        });
    }

    function updateSignInStatus(isSignedIn) {
        if (isSignedIn) {
            makeApiCall();
        }
    }


    gapi.load('client:auth2', initClient);
```

Comment: Which line calls the error? If it's the ` var request = gapi.client.sheets.spreadsheets.create({}, spreadsheetBody);` line, then you need to make sure that `gapi.client.sheets` is defined.

Comment: it is not defined ...

Answer (score 1):

It's because you've commented out the "Discovery Docs" line. GAPI needs to know the discovery docs in order to load the correct API endpoints.